# Error when connect Spring Boot + Mysql + JPA , spring can't find user

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

i need some help from you. I'm trying to start a new application from Spring Boot + Mysql + JPA. The connection worked for a time when suddenly stop. I tried to change the mysql driver but i see no changes. 
here's my application.properties

```
# ===============================
# = DATA SOURCE
# ===============================

# Set here configurations for the database connection

# Connection url for the database "netgloo_blog"
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/farmacia_da_natureza?useSSL=false

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
# Username and senha
spring.datasource.usuario = root
spring.datasource.senha = password
# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

# ===============================
# = JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================

# Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is
# stripped before adding them to the entity manager).

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update): with "update" the database
# schema will be automatically updated accordingly to java entities found in
# the project update
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = drop-and-create

# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

# Allows Hibernate to generate SQL optimized for a particular DBMS
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

and the exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.24.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.24.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.24.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:925) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.24.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1704) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.24.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1250) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.24.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2483) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.24.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2516) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.24.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2301) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.24.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.24.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.24.jar:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.24.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.24.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.24.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:117) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:365) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:194) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:460) [HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:534) [HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:151) [spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:115) [spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:78) [spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:319) [spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:356) [spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup.getDatabase(DatabaseLookup.java:72) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties.determineDatabase(JpaProperties.java:166) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:111) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$30fa9bdb.CGLIB$jpaVendorAdapter$4(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$30fa9bdb$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$cee6bf0e.invoke(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) [spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361) [spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$30fa9bdb.jpaVendorAdapter(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
(...)

2018-07-23 12:32:16.198  WARN 8940 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.a.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup           : Unable to determine jdbc url from datasource

org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta-data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:328) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:356) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup.getDatabase(DatabaseLookup.java:72) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties.determineDatabase(JpaProperties.java:166) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:111) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$30fa9bdb.CGLIB$jpaVendorAdapter$4(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$30fa9bdb$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$cee6bf0e.invoke(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) [spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361) [spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$30fa9bdb.jpaVendorAdapter(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
(...)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.24.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.24.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.24.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:925) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.24.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1704) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.24.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1250) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.24.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2483) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.24.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2516) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.24.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2301) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.24.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.24.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.24.jar:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.24.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.24.jar:na]
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.24.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:117) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:365) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:194) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:460) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:534) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:151) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:115) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:78) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
... 121 common frames omitted
```

and the main application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class FarmaciadanaturezaApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(FarmaciadanaturezaApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

and here is the pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>br.com.jamalxvi</groupId>
<artifactId>farmaciadanatureza</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>farmaciadanatureza</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.24</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


</project>
```

Thank you for the time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wrong property names, there is no such thing as `spring.datasource.usuario` and `spring.datasource.senha`. As per [Spring Boot, Appendix A docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) you need:

```
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = password
```

Comment: Thank you, i didn't see the typo. :)